# Error importing coremltools - cannot import name ParametricSoftPlus

Tags: python, ios, keras, coreml

Trying to use Apple coreML tools to convert a simple model using Keras.
I'm using Python 2.7
running this line of code:

> import coremltools

give the following error:

from keras.layers.advanced_activations import ParametricSoftPlus

ImportError: cannot import name ParametricSoftPlus

Note: i have no problem importing ParametricSoftPlus in my script:

> from keras.layers.advanced_activations import ParametricSoftPlus

Note #2: I opened the file that throws the error and if i use the same statement above, it fails with the same error.

At first I thought it could be a permission issue but if it were then no script file would be able to access keras' ParametricSoftPlus

Note #3: I can bypass that line of code in the source file and then it give me the same error for SReLU.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Keras are you using? The coremltools currently requires Keras 1.2.2. If you have a different version (such as 2.0) then it won't work.

Comment: i am using Keras 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I uninstalled all my Python libraries and reinstalled the bare minimum (yes, Keras is v.1.2.2) and it still didn't work.

I also reinstalled pip:
`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall`

Then I decided to go all out and remove Python from my system and reinstalled it. This solved my issue. Now this is NOT a solution, this is just a work around and a big WARNING... You need to reinstall python right after removing it otherwise your MAC OS will NOT WORK, you will need to reinstall your OS.

**Steps can be found in many other SO posts:**

Remove the Python 2.7 framework

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

Remove the Python 2.7 applications directory

```
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
```

Remove the symbolic links in /usr/local/bin that point to this Python `version see ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'` 
and then run the following command to remove all the links:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

If necessary, edit your shell profile file(s) to remove adding /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 to your PATH environment file. Depending on which shell you use, any of the following files may have been modified: ~/.bash_login, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.cshrc, ~/.profile, ~/.tcshrc, and/or ~/.zprofile.

Now, we can install Python 2.7:

```
$ brew install python
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: It's much easier (and safer) to create a virtualenv that references the Apple-installed version of Python. Then you can install all your dependencies inside that virtualenv. (Make the virtualenv by writing: virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 myenv)